# Вывод числа в masm, самый лёгкий способ

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Есть ли макрос или WinAPI функция, которая бы выводила число в десятичной системе счисления. На подобии `print(eax)`, а `eax` было равно 76313.

Comment: printf из msvcrt.dll (который в том или ином виде наверняка есть везде) не катит?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а почему у меня так не компилируется "printf(eax)"?

Comment: А потому что книжки читать надо: как вызывать функции, как линковать и так далее. У того же Зубкова программирование под винду описано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `printf` из msvcrt.dll.

Вот пример:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall

include c:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
include c:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc

includelib c:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.DATA
    fmt db "%d",10,0

.CODE
main PROC
    mov eax, 76313

    push eax
    push offset fmt
    call crt_printf
    sub esp, 8 ; нужно выровнять стек на размер параметров, т.к. у crt_printf соглашение вызова cdecl

    ; или просто
    ; invoke crt_printf, addr fmt, eax
    ; тогда sub esp, 8 писать не нужно макрос invoke сам его добавит

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

END main
```

По сути, вместо `"%d"` при выводе функция `printf` подставляет десятичное представление переданного ей параметра. Другие варианты: `%u` - десятичное беззнаковое целое, `%x` - шестнадцатеричное представление, `%c` - символьное представление, `%s` - строка (переданный параметр должен быть адресом строки) и прочее.

Подробнее про форматирование вывода printf можно почитать здесь (там для Си, но именно форматирование вывода остается таким же): [Функции стандартного ввода/вывода (printf, scanf)](http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/1633)

А вот про управляющие символы (которые начинаются с "\") лучше пропустить, на ассемблере это не будет работать.

Есть еще макрос printf, вот пример использования:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall

include c:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.CODE
main PROC
    printf ("%d\n", 76313);
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

END main
```

За основу обоих примеров взяты примеры из [ответа на stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34210350/4752653).

Если кому-то вдруг понадобится, вот пример использования функции `printf` из msvcrt.dll для flat assembler:

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32ax.inc'

section '.code' code readable executable
start:
    cinvoke printf, <"%d", 10, 0>, 76313
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

section '.idata' import data readable

library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll',\
        msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

include 'api\kernel32.inc'

import msvcrt,\
       printf, 'printf'
```